# add small icon to virtualtreeview

Tags: delphi, icons, virtualtreeview

i am trying to add small icon to VirtualTreeview in delphi2010
i have ImageList attached to VirtualTreeview using the property images

```
procedure TMainFrm.VSTGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
var
  FileInfo: PFileInfoRec;
begin
  if Kind in [ikNormal , ikSelected] then
  begin
    if Column = 0 then
    ImageIndex :=ImageList1.AddIcon(FileInfo.FileIco);
  end;
end;
```

but after adding the icons look too dark:

[image: screenshot]

FileInfo Strucutre (Record with methods) filled whene i load the files so
what i need is just to add the fileico from fileinfo to imagelist and display in treeview

```
type
  PFileInfoRec= ^TFileInfoRec;
  TFileInfoRec = record
  strict private
    vFullPath: string;
      .
      .
      .
    vFileIco : TIcon;
  public
    constructor Create(const FilePath: string);
    property FullPath: string read vFullPath;
      .
      .
      .
    property FileIco : TIcon  read vFileIco;
  end;
```

the constructor:

```
constructor TFileInfoRec.Create(const FilePath: string);
var
  FileInfo: SHFILEINFO;
begin
  vFullPath := FilePath;
    .
    .
    .
  vFileIco        := TIcon.Create;
  vFileIco.Handle := FileInfo.hIcon;
//  vFileIco.Free;
end;
```

so where is the probleme ? ! thanks

Comment: Looks like a problem with partial transparency. Perhaps you need to set the image list `ColorDepth` to `cd32Bit`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks but still doesn't work

Comment: OK, what exactly did you do? When precisely did you change the  `ColorDepth`? Immediately after creating the image list. Also, what does your real code look like? Presumably the real code assigns `FileInfo`. If the real code does so then it's disappointing that you posted fake code. If this is your real code then not assigning anything to `FileInfo` is clearly a problem.

Comment: And you mustn't add a new icon every time the tree view asks for the image index. Add the icon once and return the same image index every time.

Comment: David has right, you have to understand the virtual paradigm before working with Virtual TreeView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have an image list `ImageList1` and assign it to `VirtualStringTree1.Images` property. Then joining to the previous commenters, before you use `FileInfo`, assign something to it, like: `FileInfo := Sender.GetNodeData(Node)`, than you can use `FileInfo.FileIco`. But you should add your icon to the imagelist not in the `OnGetImageIndex`. You should do it in OnInitNode (if you follow the virtual paradigm, what you should do), than store the index of the added icon in FileInfo. example:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1InitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
var
  FileInfo: PFileInfoRec;
begin
  FileInfo := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  //...
  FileInfo.FileIcoIndex := ImageList1.AddIcon(FileInfo.FileIco);

end;
```

than in `onGetImageIndex`:

```
procedure TMainFrm.VSTGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
var
  FileInfo: PFileInfoRec;
begin
  FileInfo := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Kind in [ikNormal , ikSelected] then
  begin
    if Column = 0 then
    ImageIndex :=FileInfo.FileIcoIndex;
  end;
end;
```

If it's not adequate, please post more sample code, to enlighten us about your problem.

Comment: @S.FATEH You've already accepted the answer to your question. The code you added doesn't change anything for us.